# Making a timer start at a spesific point in the code

Tags: java, processing, delay, delayed-execution

ive been working on a game as of resently. At the moment im trying to create a main menu, that will co-exist and work together with my game. Ive run in to a problem unfortunetly.
I have made a "delay" timer that removes health from the user player, and a timer for the boss youre fightning, for the boss to be able to jump around the battleground after a certain delay/timer. 
this worked out fine until i tried to implement a main menu. When i put the menu in, i made it so if you press "p" it will take you in to the game and start the par of the "draw" function which has the game inside, and only then it should start the delay/timer consisting of 5000ms. The problem comes when i try to put the "delay" inside of the part that has the game in it, the delay wont work, but if i put it back where i first had it, which was in the "Setup" part, it does work only that it instead starts the timer as soon as the program is started and not the actual game. here is my code:

```
void Startmeny() {
 textSize(70);
 text("Jackan Heroes!", 300, 300);
 fill(255, 255, 0);
 textSize(40);
 text("Start", 350, 400);
 fill(255, 255, 0);
 textSize(40);
 text("Creatorer", 350, 500);
 fill(255, 255, 0);
 if (keyPressed) {
  if (key == 'p' || key == 'P') {
   start = true;
  }
 }
}


void draw() {

  textSize(70);
  text("Jackan Heroes!", 200, 300);
  fill(255, 255, 0);
  textSize(40);
  text("Start - press 'P' ", 250, 400);
  fill(255, 255, 0);
  textSize(40);
  text("Creatorer - press 'O' ", 250, 500);
  fill(255, 255, 0);
  if (keyPressed) {
   if (key == 'p' || key == 'P') {
    start = true;
   }
  }
  if (start == true) {

   background(100);

   int rT = 255;

   _delay = new Delay(5000);

   g.display();
   g.checkEdges();
   g.BarsDisplay();
   g.HealthDisplay();
   g.XpDisplay();


   f.detect();
   f.Enemy();
   f.HealthDisplay();
   f.dead();



   if (g.intersects(D)) {
    D.transport();
   }

   if (f.HP > 0) {
    if (g.intersects(f) /*|| g.Intersects(f)*/ ) {

     if (_delay.expired()) {

      g.RemoveHealth();
      _delay = new Delay(1200);
     }

     //g.knockback();
     //f.chase();
    }
   }

   if (g.intersect(f)) {

    if (!g.alreadypressed) {
     f.damage();
     textSize(32);
     text("-8 ", f.x2 + 50, f.y2 - 40);
     fill(0, 102, 153);
    }
    g.alreadypressed = true;
   }




   if (_delay.expired()) {
    if (f.yes == true) {

     float R = random(100, 700);
     f.x2 = R;
     f.xd = f.x2 + 50;
     float R2 = random(100, 700);
     f.y2 = R2;
     f.yd = f.y2 + 50;
     _delay = new Delay(3000);
    }
   }
```

some of the code names are in swedish so ill translate the important one.
startmeny = "the menu"
if there are any more you dont understand ill tranlsate them.
:)

Comment: In the `draw()` method, you reset the timer with `_delay = new Delay(5000);`. The `draw()` method loops several times per second. Your timer may be working, but it'll never expire as it's always being reset. That's also why initializing it in the `setup()` method worked right: that method only run once.

Comment: oooohh, yeah that's it. Is there a way to make a function inside of "draw" only run once, once "draw" has been activated for the first time?

Comment: Sure, I was already writing you a simple idea to do just that. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing much of your code, you could fix the initial issue like this:

```
  if (keyPressed) {
   if (!start && (key == 'p' || key == 'P')) {
    start = true;
    _delay = new Delay(5000); //of course, remove this line from where I took it
   }
  }
```

This said, you initialize `_delay` at several places in the code. Are these delays all different timers? If so, they would need to be initialized as different variables. Every time you re-initialize `_delay`, you "forget" the old delay and just start a new one. Sounds to me like the 5 seconds initial delay was the only problematic one, but I though you might want to know anyway.

Have fun!